# How to use jmeter to test an Oracle Stored Procedure with sys_refcursor return type?

Tags: oracle, testing, stored-procedures, jmeter, sys-refcursor

I want to test an Oracle Stored Procedure by using jmeter.I have done everything but parameters.

And here is my SQL Query:

> declare 
>        outinfo varchar2(20);
>        outtable sys_refcursor;
>        begin
>        {call RK_JSCX(?,?)};
>        end;

The outtable in Oracle is a cursor.And i used resultSet to contain it in java.However,whatever i set in parameter types ,it said invalid type.

> Sample Start: 2012-10-25 16:06:41 CST
>   Load time: 0
>   Latency: 0
>   Size in bytes: 25
>   Headers size in bytes: 0
>   Body size in bytes: 25
>   Sample Count: 1
>   Error Count: 1
>   Response code: null 0
>   Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid data type: cursor

Response headers:
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@58ba09

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: UTF-8

How can fix it?
   Thanks!

Here is my code in java:

```
public String RK_JSCX() throws Exception {

    RK_JSCX_Response response = null;
    List<RK_JSCX_Outtable> list = null;
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = null; 
    try {
        sql = "{call RK_JSCX(?,?)}";
        con = ConnectionUtils.getInstance().getConnect();

        if (con.isClosed()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ERROR.THE   CONNECTION   ISCLOSED");
        }

        cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

        cs.execute();

        rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
        list = new ArrayList<RK_JSCX_Outtable>();
        while (rs.next()) {

            RK_JSCX_Outtable out = new RK_JSCX_Outtable(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6));

            list.add(out);
        }
        String outInfo = cs.getString(2);
        response = new RK_JSCX_Response(list, outInfo);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally {

        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                if (cs != null) {
                    cs.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return JSON.toJSONString(response);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you are calling your oracle stored procedure from java?

Comment: So you are getting exception here `cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);` And your procedure receives a parameter right?

Comment: What does this return when you execute this from sqlplus or from backend? `declare outinfo varchar2(20); outtable sys_refcursor; begin {call RK_JSCX(?,?)}; end;`

Comment: Everything is ok when i run java application.My procedure receives two parameters.One is a cursor ,the other is a varchar.

Comment: I have not execute this code in PL/SQL yet.

Comment: Try executing from backend and see what does this return? Another point is does RK_JSCX is doing any insert/update or delete? if not use a function and return sys_refcursor.

Comment: Some procedures do insert,some not.Should i modify all of these?

Comment: If your RK_JSCX is doing only select and not any insert/update or delete better use a function and retrun sys_refcursor. And have you checked the results when you executed your procedure from backend to verify it is working fine?

Comment: Yeah. It works well when i execute it from backend.The problem is it doesn't always work when i do loadtest with soapui. Sometimes it returns null,sometimes it returns double value.So i want to test procedure to see if it is ok or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it:

- SQL Query : call RK_JSCX(?,?)
- Parameter values : OUT, OUT
- Parameter types : OUT -10,OUT VARCHAR

  -10 being the int value of OracleTypes.CURSOR
- Variable names:  cursor, outInfo

  ```
   Names are what you want
  ```

JMeter allows using more types than java.sql.Types constants, in this case instead of using Constant names, you use integer values of constants.

Documentation has been clarified (in next JMeter version) , see:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54048

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I realize the types mistake.Can it be fixed?Do you mean I should use other sampler?I read the docs of JSR223 Sampler,but I still don't know how to do with it.

Comment: Hello, yes that what i am proposing. Code the jdbc call in java and call it through jsr223 sampler.  Search for examples on SO using OracleTypes.CURSOR and OracleCallableStatement.

Comment: In act my initial answer was wrong, I updated it and tested it.

Comment: Thank you.I got the cursor,but the value is an object id likes oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@b2d7e8.I also want to get the value in the cursor.

Comment: You will have to process this one in a beanshell sampler.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following changes

change the syntax in calling the procedure to

```
cs = con.prepareCall("BEGIN RK_JSCX(?, ?); END;");
```

And I believe your first OUT parameter is VARCHAR2 right? so

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
```

then
use the following to cast CallableStatement

```
rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).getCursor(2);
```

Update 1

I have changed your procedure to demonstrate working version

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rk_jscx (outtable   OUT sys_refcursor,
                                                 outinfo    OUT VARCHAR2
                                                )
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN outtable FOR
        SELECT  SYSDATE
          FROM  DUAL;

    outinfo := 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        outinfo := 2;
        ROLLBACK;
END rk_jscx;
```

Java Code

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN rk_jscx(?, ?); END;");
 stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
 stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
 stmt.execute();
      ResultSet rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getCursor(1);
      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getDate("sysdate")); 
      }
```

The above prints `2012-10-23`

Check your jdbc driver as well

Comment: There is a ClassCastException. Because con.prepareCall() returns a CallableStatement and it cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement

Comment: Where are you getting ClassCastException? At this line `rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).getCursor(2);` ?

Comment: Yes,I get ClassCastException at this line.

Comment: Try `cs = (CallableStatement)con.prepareCall();`

Comment: More information you can find [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php)

Comment: It doesn't work.I think that CallableStatement doesn't allow be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement in java.

Comment: May be a driver issue then. The link I have posted above is quite helpful.

Comment: By the way have you changed the order because your first OUT param is VARCHAR2 and then sys_refcursor.

Comment: Oh,the first is sys_refcursor .

Comment: Here is my procedure:create or replace procedure RK_JSCX
(
   OUTTABLE out sys_refcursor,
   OUTINFO out varchar2
) 
as
begin
   open OUTTABLE for select PONUM,ITEMNUM,DESCRIPTION,CSTM_MOD,ORDERQTY,REQUESTEDBY from RECMAT;
   
   OUTINFO:=1;
   
   exception
     when no_data_found then 
     OUTINFO :=2;
     rollback; 
     
end RK_JSCX;

Comment: @luting I have updated my answer. Please have a look. Regards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.It still doesn't work.And I find others have  ClassCastException as well.What't more, my old code works well when it is not in concurrency environment.And my purpose is testing the performance of procedure to ensure if my java code is ok in concurrency environment.

Comment: @luting I strongly believe this could be a case with jdbc driver. Which jdbc driver do you use for your application?

Comment: That is right. Try removing cast for callablestatement  and see.

Comment: Another point is data type you are trying to fetch from database using cursor are of same data types? Like date, number etc.

Comment: Looks like you are not alone. http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlexception+invalid+data+type+cursor+jmeter