# Create stored procedure which returns in one OUT param database version (Oracle)

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I new with PL\SQL so i'm traying to make a procedure witch return database version with OUT in one param. My SQL code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getVersion(outParam1 OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  outParam1 := SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
END;
```

Can some one explain me how to write procedure right way and how to execute the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getVersion (out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END getVersion;
```

In order to execute from `SQL Plus`, do as

```
VARIABLE mycursor REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
   getVersion (:mycursor);
END;
/

PRINT mycursor
```

From `SQL Developer` do as

```
var mycursor refcursor
exec getVersion(:mycursor)
print mycursor
```

If you would like to have OUT varchar2 with a single row, then you could something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc (outParam1 OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT dummy INTO outParam1 FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END myProc;
```

and execute as

```
VARIABLE testvar VARCHAR2(16);

EXEC myProc(:testvar);

PRINT testvar;
```

Comment: Tnx! I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. Is code the same for executing?

Comment: Do you have any idea whay i get error when i try to execute 
VAR mycursor refcursor
exec getVersion(:mycursor)
print mycursor

The error is: exec getVersion(:mycursor), object HR.GETVERSION is invalid

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik check `GETVERSION` object is compiled properly.

Comment: No it's not. But when i try to compile, it returns error object does not exist...

ALTER PROCEDURE getVersion COMPILE;
and i get ORA-04043: object GETVERSION does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56480/discussion-between-polppan-and-davor-bramor-pecnik).

Comment: I got one more question for you! :)
If i wnat to implement this in java code what would be the query
String sql = " ";

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik You mean how this would called from Java using JDBC?

Comment: Yes... right nove i have
String sql = "var mycursor refcursor; exec getVersion(:mycursor); print mycursor;";

error is: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13028735/599528). If you have any issue then post another question with the issues you are facing.

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik This [too](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php) would help you.

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478480/scout-framework-on-button-click-populate-string-field-with-database-value) question of accessing stored procedure from Java?

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik Let me when know if you are facing any issues while trying to access your stored procedure.

Comment: Chan you chekc that second question again?
I'm having some troubles how to System.out.println("banner data")