# How to do performance test for a Stored Procedure via JMeter 2.9

Tags: stored-procedures, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, postgresql-9.2

I have done performance testing of normal select and update queries.

I want to know the procedure of testing a postgres stored procedure in JMeter 2.9.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tutorial:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

And read the documentation of the involved components:

- [JDBC Connection configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)
- [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

For stored procedure have a look at this:

[How to use jmeter to test an Oracle Stored Procedure with sys_refcursor return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026140/how-to-use-jmeter-to-test-an-oracle-stored-procedure-with-sys-refcursor-return-t)

By the way you should upgrade to JMete 2.11.